# how to add `List<string>` in DTO in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

how to get list of DTO?

```
@Override
public void updateOrganization(OrganizationDTO orgDTO, Users loggedInUser){
}
```

`OrganizationDTO` has a new `List<String> loginId` as new field.
after these changes in my code `DTO` and service layer i am getting `400 Bad Request`. On my browser console it is may be due to `jackson mapper` but how to overcome it.
and if i make it a `String loginId` instead of `List<String> loginId` it works fine with `String loginId`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateOrg.html", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody String updateOrgData(@RequestBody OrganizationDTO orgDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestWrapper req = new RequestWrapper(request);
        orgWizardService.updateOrganization(orgDTO, req.getLoggedInUser());
        return new AjaxResponseWrapper(orgDTO.getClientCode()).getJson();
    }
```

Comment: As you are getting `400 Bad Request`, check your payload. Your json payload must be same as the Request Body dto.

Comment: yes i have checked it should be `List<String> loginId` but it seems as simple `String loginId ` how do i change it.

Comment: Post your code and post request payload.

Answer (score 2):

It's very nice that u provided your payload, since 'loginId' is a list of string use the below syntax in your payload

```
"loginId" : [ "admin@prawaa.org","string2", "string3"]
```

current syntax u have used is

```
"loginId":"admin@abc.com"
```